# How to load new pages generated server-side into a PhoneGap or Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, laravel, cordova, laravel-5, phonegap

I'm trying to figure out the easiest and quickest technique to adapt our company's website to an app that can be downloaded from the app stores. PhoneGap/Cordova looks the way to go. Using the InAppBrowser plugin looks like an obvious route but we're going to need access to some phone APIs via Cordova plugins and there seems no way to access data from them in the InAppBrowser (Webview?) window.

As an alternative I'm wondering why can't I simply replace the HTML content directly in my PhoneGap page (effectively a single page app) with new HTML page content loaded from our server? We're using Laravel templates server-side, so there is already a page wrapper into which Laravel injects page-specific content (on the server) before sending to the client. I could just move the page wrapper HTML to the front end (into the SPA compiled into my PhoneGap app) complete with all the JS and CSS needed across all pages, and then just live load new page content into the DOM (e.g. in the page BODY), and any JS would have access to phone APIs via Cordova plugins.

Is this feasible, or am I missing something? (any gotchas?)

Thanks.

Comment: Have u implemented it ?

Comment: i got exact requirement now, it will be helpful how did u achieve it ?

Comment: @NareshKumar I don't think I ever actually implemented this but the accepted answer below looks correct I think (though I haven't tried it) so suggest using that? It is very simple to achieve this in theory, just load the content via AJAX and then use e.g. JQuery (or whatever) to replace the content of the element on that page that you want to use to show the content you loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

**in your serveur create page home.php like this :**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("content-type: text/javascript");

          if(isset($_POST['home']))
           {
            $content_html = '<head><title> Test </title></head><body><span>working</span></body><script>declare  all necessary script hear</script>';
                  echo json_encode($content_html);  
            }
?>
```

**in cordova index.html**

```
<html id="new_content">


</html>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
       $('#new_content').html("<center><span>Loading ...</span></center>");
                  $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http:/your_serveur/home.php",
                         data: {"home":"home"},
                         cache: false,
                         async:false,
                         success: function(data){   
                           var data = JSON.parse(data); 
                            $("#new_content").html(data);
                              },
                        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I suppose it has to be sent as JSON encoded? Is that the only format? OK if so, just wanted to be sure. And is the Access Control header because the response is in JSON? Also, could the Javascript defined on the PHP side ("declare  all necessary script here") just be moved into <script> tags in the cordovaindex.html? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is sent via JSON encoded it's fast and secure,
Access-Control-Allow-Origin if you send request from http serveur ,
yes you can declare all script in cordovaindex.html instead PHP side.
i use like this example in my app and it's work perfect
, `u welcome`

Comment: Great thanks. I presume this works over HTTPS? Also, what about cookies - will they work? I don't want my users to get logged out on each new page view :) Thanks

Comment: yes work with HTTPS&HTTP , yes you can use cookies in javascript and call in all you page without logged , uwelcome